# Why should we preceed neostigmine by atropine in tubocurarine toxicity?

Tags: pharmacology, autonomic-nervous-system

Why should we precede neostigmine by atropine in tubocurarine toxicity ?

I know that neostigmine act as anticholinesterase thus increasing the number of Ach molecules rendering them able to displace the tubocurarine, but I don't get the idea of atropine I know it's muscarinic inhibitor but we are speaking about nicotinergic receptors?

Comment: Please present your thoughts on the topic or at least an attempt at finding out the answer you seek. What are the actions and target sites of neostigmine and atropine?

Comment: I know that neostigmine act as anticholinesterase thus increasing the number of Ach molecules rendering them able to displace the tubocurarine , but I don't get the idea of atropine I know it's muscarinic inhibitor but we are speaking about N receptors

Answer (score 2):

[Tubocurarine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubocurarine_chloride#Clinical_pharmacology) is a non-depolarising neuromuscular blocking aqgent, that is, it acts as a competetive antagonist of Acetyl Choline at the Nicotinic receptors.(Toxicity/Effect: $-N$)

[Atropine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atropine#Mechanism_of_action) is a competitive antagonist of the muscarinic acetylcholine receptor, classified as an anticholinergic. (Effect: $-M$)

[Neostigmine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neostigmine#Pharmacology) blocks acetylcholinesterase, increasing the concentration of ACh at, and stimulating both muscarinic and nicotinic receptors. (Effect: $+M+N$)

Hence, to counter the only nicotinic deficiency of ACh, we give Neostigmine, which will also stimulate the muscarinic receptors, leading to muscarinic side effects. To counter the latter, atropine is given. A similar formulation is used in a disease like [Myasthenia Gravis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myasthenia_gravis), with a functionally similar lesion.
$$(+M+N)+(-M)+(-N)=0$$